# MAX(IF()) PIVOT produce error if I change my column value to string

Tags: mysql

I have this error.

When I change column `Question name` value from int ex `1` to string ex `Q1` my query will now produce an error

My first query has no problem when the values of `Question name` are `integer` data type

[image]

But when I change values to string like you see below it produce an error

[image]
I use this query

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(`Question name` = ', `Question name`, ',`mark`,NULL))')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Question;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `Grade`.`grade`, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM `User` join `Grade` on `User`.`id` = `Grade`.`user_id` 
                  join `Question` on `User`.`id` = `Question`.`user_id` GROUP BY `User`.`id`');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Because strings need to be put in quotes like this `'Q1'`

Comment: @juergend can you point which should I put the single quote?

Comment: this 

'MAX(IF(`Question name` = ', `Question name`, ',`mark`,NULL))')

should be :

'MAX(IF(`Question name` = "', `Question name`, '",`mark`,NULL))')

Comment: @2oppin ops solve. thank for the help. Can I close this post now?

Comment: posted it as an answer, for you can mark it and close the thread :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add quotes
this:

'MAX(IF(Question name = ', Question name, ',mark,NULL))')

should be :

'MAX(IF(Question name = "', Question name, '",mark,NULL))'